# Rails include all "parent" records in where clause on nested includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a query like this:

```
Model.includes(other_models: still_more_models).where(still_more_models: { property: "X" }).find(1)
```

It's almost working as I expect, however it does not include `other_models` unless they have an associated `still_more_models`. How can I include *all* `other_models`, regardless of whether or not they have `still_more_models where property = "X"` associated?

Comment: Very confused with your question. 
Firstly, If you want to find the `Model` with id = 1, you don't need the `includes` and the `where`. Secondly, **it does not include other_models unless they have an associated still_more_models** and **How can I include all other_models, regardless of whether or not they have still_more_models where property = "X"** are 2 different issues.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're probably wanting to experiment with different join types. I don't know all the rails methods for this off the top of my head, but `left_outer_joins` is one.

Alternatively you can specify the join type by hand in a SQL string.

It is also sometimes helpful to come up with the raw SQL that does what you want, and ask for help to get the right rails AR query to represent it.